# Log4j logging to wrong log file in Weblogic

Tags: java, log4j, weblogic11g

**Context:**
I have two java applications (A.EAR and B.EAR) deployed in weblogic. Both applications have their own log4j jars bundled inside the EARs (packaged as maven dependencies). I have used saperate log4j.properties (a-log4j.properties and b-log4j.properties) files for both these applications and specified that they log to different log files (a.log and b.log).

**Problem:**
When I run just the application A, I get the logs in a.log. but after a while when I start the application B, both application A and B log to b.log. Nothing else is written in a.log until a restart on A is performed. 
In simple terms, which ever application I start at the last all the applications logs are written into that application's logs. Does anyone know why this could be happening?

I am using WebLogic 11g and log4j 1.2.17.

**Solution/Fix:**

Aparently, if this is the case it means that as both web apps would share a root classloader serving the global libraries load by Weblogic, we need to specify to load the application classes after the server classes. This could be done by:

```
<wls:prefer-application-packages>
<wls:package-name>org.apache.log4j.*</wls:package-name> 
</wls:prefer-application-packages>
```

In versions older than 10.3.3 like 11g you can do this as:

```
<prefer-application-packages>
<package-name>org.apache.log4j.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```

Comment: How are you packaging your EAR. kindly attach a snapshot to the question